# javaw.exe high cpu usage

Tags: java, java-7

I have created a runnable jar, which runs on a single thread. The thread executes a for loop having 100 iteration. However the cpu usgae goes upto 60% on i3 processor win7 64 bit machine.
I tried to analyze the cpu usage in [process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

The native threads are consuming CPUs. 
The native threads are all at msvcr100.dll!endthreadex+0x60
consuming cpu
I am using jdl 1.7.
Can somebody please suggest what might be going wrong here.

Here is the code:
the app accepts socket connection and processes the  date sent by the client.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Socket sock = ssock.accept();   
        // This is the function which has the for loop          
        obj.MyFunction();           
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {               
        ssock.close();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}                   

void MyFunction()
{
    for(int i=0; i < 1000;i++)
    {
         // Processing done here
    }
}
```

Comment: It  might help if you show your code here !!

Comment: just posted the code

Comment: here is the link to the image of analysis done by Process Explorer
[link](http://www.123dl.org/installer/C/processs.png)

Comment: What kind of processing happens in `MyFunction`? If it runs for ~1400 ms and consumes 100% of CPU, the average load will be 60% together with a 1000 ms sleep. (It also helps to give `MyFun` and `MyFunction` the same name, and decide if you run 100 or 1000 iterations.)

Comment: The `sleep()` is not necessary here. `accept()` wil block & wait anyway.

Comment: Yes accept() is not needed there.
Regarding MyFunction(). it contains code to parse xml. I pass data accross process in form of xml, The function iterates all the nodes to fetch the data. All this happens in single thread. The cpu usage ranges from 40 % to 60 % sometimes even freezing my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Profile your code, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#jconsole for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you try this:

```
ex.printStackTrace();
```

you might get some more information. Right now, when you get an exception, you have no idea what happened or why. You are silent about it, which is rarely the right behavior for hitting exceptions.

What is the processing? If you're trying to do a lot of work, it might not be unexpected to go to 60% cpu. What's the Big O runtime of your algo? What's the data set size?

Comment: egarding MyFunction(). it contains code to parse xml. I pass data accross process in form of xml, The function iterates all the nodes to fetch the data. All this happens in single thread. The cpu usage ranges from 40 % to 60 % sometimes even freezing my machine

Comment: here is the link to the image of analysis done by Process Explorer [link](http://www.123dl.org/installer/C/processs.png).
Why would native thread take maximum cpu cycle?

Comment: Why some code takes a lot of time is a very wide question with too many answers to iterate. All slowness problems eventually boil down to either an algorithmic and technical problem. If you can speak on the algorithmic complexity of what you are doing, it would be possible to to pursue the technical reasons for slowness, but as it stands, I don't feel like ruling out inefficient algorithms would be correct.